# Icons too small, 2023-07-03 GIMP 2.10.34

Tags: multiple-monitors, icons, gimp

2023-07-03
Windows 10 - up to date.

Tags: Brush-icons-unreadable
left-side-icons-excellent
Windows10
Gimp2.10.34
Uniform-icon-size-not-respected

After a fresh install of GIMP 2.10.34:

The left icons are properly sized. Brush icons on the right side are unusable on both the 4K added monitor and the laptop monitor - both used as two side-by-side monitors. Somehow, Gimp 2.10.34 does not uniformly scale icons. Left side
exactly as expected, the right side (e.g. brushes) is broken and unusable on 4k and 2k monitors. (That would be HD and UHD monitors.) Gimp 2.10.34 starts up on
the 4k monitor.

The default monitor after reboot, is the 4k monitor. My Windows 10 uses the 4k monitor as the default monitor.

Is there anything I can do? If editing gtkrc file is the solution which of the 13 or so do I edit? Which file does the brush icon display get its "icon size" from?